# navigator.geolocation.watchPosition returns NaN in speed

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, geolocation, gps

I'm having issues getting the speed from the GPS in phonegap/cordova on iOS. It returns NaN no matter if I'm driving in my car or just standing still.

```
    function speed_start() {
        speed_timer_id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(speed_update_data,
                                                  speed_update_error,
                                                  { enableHighAccuracy: true });
}

var speed_update_data = function(position) {
        $("#speed-debug").html('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
              'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
              'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
              'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
              'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
              'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
              'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

var speed_update_error = function(error) {
        $("#speed-debug").html(error.message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a hardware "issue". Seems that the GPS didn't have enough signal.